# Maintaining tabs across all scenes using React Native Router Flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Does anyone know if it is possible to maintain the tabs (tab bar) across all scenes in React Native Router Flux?

Example of what I am trying to achieve is, in the below example, I want to show the tabs "Home" and "PictureList" on all scenes, in the example also the "PictureDetail" scene. But I do not want PictureDetailScene to be included as a tab in the actual tab bar. Basically want to maintain a tab bar as a global navigation across all other scenes.

Is this possible? Or would I need to create my own tab bar and maintain it outside RNRF?

```
<RootScene>
  <Tabs>
     <HomeScene>
     <PictureListScene>
  </Tabs>
  <PictureDetailScene>
</RootScene>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `clone` prop to your `PictureDetailScene`. That whay it will use the Scene it was called from as a template. So if it is called from a tabScene, it will use the tab scene as a template and show the tabbar.

```
<RootScene>
  <Tabs>
     <HomeScene>
     <PictureListScene>
  </Tabs>
  <PictureDetailScene clone>
</RootScene>
```

#### Edit

If you are pushing `PictureDetailScene` from `PictureListScene` why don't you place your `PictureDetailScene` and `PictureListScene` inside a Scene stack as follows:

*(notice that for a `Scene` to have nested Scenes in it, the parent should not have a component assigned to it (prop `component` is not set)*

```
<RootScene>
  <Tabs>
    <HomeScene>
    <Scene key="YOUR_PICTURE_LIST_KEY">
      <PictureListScene>
      <PictureDetailScene clone>
    </Scene>
  </Tabs>
</RootScene>
```

Let me know if that works for you. If not I'll spin a quick RNRF project and share the working code for yor case with you

Comment: I tried the edited version and that does work. It seems I don't even need to add the `clone` attribute. I left all the attributes of the PictureListScene in the parent component, except the `component` attribute, which is the only attribute of the first child in new parent scene. I was wondering how it knows that this is the child to be shown when clicking that tab? It seems to be based on order? Is that a good way to do it, or would you recommend using `initial`?

Comment: It works both way @Quach90. The stack is read in order indeed and the first scene is presented first unless ‘initial’ is set on a different scene. You got it all right :)